# openshift v3 deploy not working

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying to migrate my java/tomcat application to openshift v3. I have set up the build s2i to point to my git repository, it finds the pom.xml and builds everything, it then displays the message "Copying all war artifacts from /tmp/src/target directory into /opt/webserver/webapps for later deployment...", it then does the docker push. Everything seems ok to this point.  The application gets deployed and I connect to the terminal - I see all the artifacts in /tmp/src/target, but NOT in /opt/webserver/webapps ? I only see the manager app. When I navigate to the URL I get "page can't be found" and in the pod logs I see it is being hit ok. I just noticed ROOT.war is in /tmp/src/webapps.

Comment: It sounds like you may have specified `<outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>` in your `pom.xml` under the `maven-war-plugin`. The built `war` file then wouldn't be found in the expected `/tmp/src/target`, thus not copied into the `/opt/webserver/webapps` directory. If there would be a `war` file in the location, you should see a message in the log that the file has been copied, right under the *"Copying all war artifacts from..."* line.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed the issue.