# OpenShift Pro - Tomcat Running But App Not Started

Tags: java, openshift, tomcat8

I've upgraded to **OpenShift Pro** and I am trying to get one of my own web apps to work.

The source code is on **GitHub** and any code I push from my local IDE causes a build, so that all seems ok.

Tomcat is running, I can see that when I enter the url **/docs**. But my app is not running.

The logs show (abbreviated for clarity):

```
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
Deploying web application directory /deployments/manager
Deployment of web application directory /deployments/manager has finished in 1,762 ms
Deploying web application directory /deployments/docs
Deployment of web application directory /deployments/docs has finished in 514 ms
Deploying web application directory /deployments/host-manager
Deployment of web application directory /deployments/host-manager has finished in 471 ms
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Server startup in 2815 ms
```

As you can see, **manager**, **docs** and **host-manager** have all started but I was expecting to see something like the following after the **Starting Servlet Engine** line:

```
Deploying web application archive /deployments/ROOT.war
Deployment of web application archive /deployments/ROOT.war has finished in 2,560 ms
```

Please note that the **OpenShift App** name is not the same as my local **Eclipse Project** name. When I run this Eclipse Project locally the context is 'stripes', and a request looks like localhost:8080/stripes/Test.action

Any ideas?

Have I missed something out?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Can you provide the build log and possibly your `pom.xml`? If I'm to guess, as it sounds like the app is built fine, but the created `ROOT.war` is not deployed, I'd point you to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234420/openshift-v3-deploy-not-working?noredirect=1#comment79442738_46234420).

Comment: Jiri, thanks for that, you may be onto something. My pom.xml does indeed have the entry <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory> in it. I will remove and rebuild. I will let you know the outcome...

Comment: Jiri, you're a star. That was the problem. If you want to provide it as the answer I can give you the credit you deserve. Thanks...

Comment: Looks like this could be difficult to spot, so I added the answer below. Thanks for confirming back this was the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that in this case, the built `ROOT.war` was not found in the `/tmp/src/target` directory and deployed automatically by the s2i image.

This could be somehow tricky to spot, as the build log is just missing one line in that case. If the built war file is in the correct location, you should see a message in the log that the `ROOT.war` file (or any other name, if not deploying in the root context) has been copied into the `/opt/webserver/webapps/` directory, right under the *"Copying all target war artifacts from..."* line, such as:

```
(...)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:02.946s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 08 13:59:42 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/288M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copying all target war artifacts from /home/jboss/source/target directory into /opt/webserver/webapps for later deployment...
'/home/jboss/source/target/ROOT.war' -> '/opt/webserver/webapps/ROOT.war'
(...)
```

Comment: Just to be clear on this, I removed <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory> from my pom.xml: 

   <build>
    <finalName>stripes</finalName>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>    ***** THIS LINE *****
                           <warName>ROOT</warName>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>